# TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined at compareResults

Tags: javascript, replace

```
function generateBC(url, separator) {
var splitthis = url.split("/");
var MiddleBit = [];
var RemoveFirstElement = splitthis.shift(); 
var RemoveLastElement  = splitthis.pop(); 
var RemoveLastElementDot = RemoveLastElement.substring(0, RemoveLastElement.indexOf('.')).toUpperCase();
var arrayLength = splitthis.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
 var elementOk =  splitthis[i].toUpperCase();
var urlOk = "<a href='/pictures/'>" + elementOk + "</a>";
  MiddleBit.push(urlOk);
 }
var ConMiddleBitS = String(MiddleBit).replace(/,/g , separator);
var completed = '<a href="/">HOME</a> ' + separator + ConMiddleBitS + separator + "<span class='active'>" + RemoveLastElementDot + "</span>" ;
document.write(completed);
}
generateBC("mysite.com/pictures/hotels/tens/holidays.html", " : ");
```

I don't know why I get

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
>      at compareResults` on .replace() ?

Can someone please explain why, as I see nothing wrong with the above.

Thank-you!

Comment: That code runs fine without any errors (not sure if it is doing what you expect but no errors in the console). https://jsfiddle.net/qoxcw5zo/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to use a String method on an array. Have you tried joining the array and the using the `replace()` method?

`var ConMiddleBitS = MiddleBit.join('').replace(/,/g , separator);`

EDIT:

If you're trying to remove the `,` from the array you don't have to use replace, you can just do `MiddleBit = MiddleBit.join(separator)`.

Comment: String(['a','b','c']) returns "a,b,c"

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Did not know that. But still using `.join()` is more efficient.

Comment: Yes! You're right! with join('') you don't need to replace comma.